# Xamarin.Forms iOS AbsoluteLayout child layout bounds not updated properly when adding the child view content as ScrollView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, absolutelayout

#### Description

AbsoluteLayout child layout bounds not updated properly after translate y position when adding the child view content as ScrollView in Xamarin.Forms iOS.

#### Code

[XAML]

```
    <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
    <local:CustomView x:Name="viewcustom" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="SizeProportional" 
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView" >
            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 1" />
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 2" />
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 3"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 4"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 5"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 6"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 7"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 8"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 9"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 10"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 11"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 12"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 13"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 14"/>
                <Button Margin="10" Text="Button 15"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
 </local:CustomView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

[CustomViewRenderer.cs]

```
    private void OnPanning()
    {
        var currentY = this.panGesture.TranslationInView(this).Y;
        Double screenHeigth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;

        switch (this.panGesture.State)
        {
            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
                DependencyService.Get<IAnimate>().TranslateYTo(this.view, this.prevTranslatedY, currentY, 300);
                UpdateHeight(currentY, 0);
                break;

            case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
                ...
                DependencyService.Get<IAnimate>().TranslateYTo(this.view, this.prevTranslatedY, currentY, 300);
                UpdateHeight(currentY, 0);
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
    private void UpdateHeight(double y, double viewY) //&& this.backdrop.IsBackLayerRevealed && !isPanningEnabled
    {
        Double screenHeigth = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height / DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Density;
        var heightPercentage = (screenHeigth - y) / screenHeigth;
        Xamarin.Forms.AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(view, new Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle(0, viewY, 1, heightPercentage));
    }
```

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Select the button1 then drag in downward direction.
2. And select the same button and drag in upward direction.

#### Expected Behavior

The view drag with the mouse point

#### Actual Behavior

The view not drag with the mouse point due to bounds not updated properly.

#### Basic Information

VS 2019
Tested device: iPhone simulator
XF version: 4.8

#### Output Video

[OutputVideo.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/6617118/OutputVideo.zip)

#### Sample Link

[AbsoluteLayoutContentScrollDemo.zip](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/files/6617120/AbsoluteLayoutContentScrollDemo.zip)

Comment: Does it work if it's not wrapped in a ScrollView?

Comment: I think I ran into the same issue. I'm not using `ScrollView`. A workaround for me was replacing the `StackLayout` with a `Grid`